# Change Binding depending on RadioButton

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, radio-button, tuples

I have a textbox with an Binding to an ObservableCollection with a triple tuple and want to change the Binding depending on two radiobuttons:

**XAML:**

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataInformation, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox x:Name="xTextbox" Grid.Row="0"
                        IsReadOnly="True"
                        Text="{Binding Path=Item2 , Mode=OneWay}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl  >

<RadioButton Grid.Row="1"
        x:Name="PatoRadioButton" 
        Width="150"
        Content="Type Pato"
        Checked="PatoRadioButtonChecked" />

<RadioButton Grid.Row="2"
        x:Name="FifoRadioButton" 
        Width="150"
        Content="Type Fifo"
        Checked="FifoRadioButtonChecked" />
```

**VIEWMODEL:**

```
private ObservableCollection<Tuple<int, string, string>> dataInformation;

public ObservableCollection<Tuple<int, string, string>> DataInformation
{
    get
    {
        return DataInformation;
    }

    set
    {
        dataInformation = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("DataInformation");
    }
}
```

---

**QUESTION:**

How can I change the `Text="{Binding Path=Item2 , Mode=OneWay}"` of the `TextBox` depending on the checked `RadioButton`?

- PatoRadioButton is checked then: `Text="{Binding Path=Item2 , Mode=OneWay}"`
- FifoRadioButton is checked then: `Text="{Binding Path=Item3 , Mode=OneWay}"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add 2 `Triggers` to the `TextBox` of your `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBox x:Name="xTextbox" Grid.Row="0" IsReadOnly="True">
        <TextBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, 
                                 ElementName=PatoRadioButton}" Value="True">
                        <DataTrigger.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=Item2, 
                                    Mode=OneWay" />
                        </DataTrigger.Setters>
                    </DataTrigger>

                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, 
                                 ElementName=FifoRadioButton}" Value="True">
                        <DataTrigger.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=Item3, 
                                    Mode=OneWay}" />
                        </DataTrigger.Setters>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>
</DataTemplate>
```

The triggers will set the `Binding` of the `TextBlock` when the `IsChecked` property is changed.